Plot contours from discrete data in matplotlib
How do I make a contourf plot where the areas are supposed to be discrete (integer array instead of float)?
The values should discretely mapped to color indices. Instead matplotlib just scales the result across the whole set of colors.
Example:
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

axes = (np.linspace(-2, 2, 100), np.linspace(-2, 2, 100))
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(*axes, indexing="xy")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
z = np.abs(xx * yy).astype(int)  # values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
z[z==0] = 4
ax.contourf(xx, yy, z, cmap="Set1")




Are you looking for ax.pcolormesh?

Just tried it, but also don't know how to limit the color scale. It's also using up the whole space from red to gray. Guess need to normalize somehow, but there's also no example for discrete coloring

Now I got it :)  Thanks @jared, pcolormesh was the right function, but I have to explicitly map the colors as the plotted variable:
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

axes = (np.linspace(-2, 2, 100), np.linspace(-2, 2, 100))
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(*axes, indexing="xy")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
z = np.abs(xx * yy).astype(int)  # values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
z[z==0] = 4

cmap = plt.get_cmap("Set1")   
z_color = cmap(z)  # shape (100, 100, 4) with `z` as index
ax.pcolormesh(xx, yy, z_color)


